# Method to calculate 'mechListMIC' for SPNEGO GSS-API(NTLMSSP_AUTH) accept-completed(0) state

Tags: smb, cifs, spnego

I am trying to learn and implement SMB2 Server. I am very interested to learn **GSS-API (NTLMSSP, NTLMSSP_AUTH)** inside. So, I am doing experiment with my own component of GSS-API. I read the description of mechListMIC in **RFC4178 & RFC2478**. But I couldn’t understand how to calculate **mechListMIC** for **‘SessionSetup Response, Unknown message type’** response.

Actually, I can generate the mechListMIC for negTokenInit phase of **‘NegotiateProtocol Response’**. But the problem is, when client sends **‘SessionSetup Request, NTLMSSP_AUTH, User: Domain\Administrator, Unknown message type’** request, I can’t understand how is it generating *‘mechListMIC: 01 00 00 00 78 1E E9 4A DB 99 7F E9 00 00 00 00’* and how should I send response back in **‘SessionSetup Response, Unknown message type’** with corresponding **mechListMIC** based on the previous SessionSetup Request.

I tried with the following Info:
**SMB2.CSessionSetup.securityBlob.GSSAPI.InitialContextToken.InnerContextToken.SpnegoToken.NegTokenInit.MechTypes , hex data = 30 0C 06 0A 2B 06 01 04 01 82 37 02 02 0A**

AND
**SMB2.CSessionSetup.securityBlob.GSSAPI.NegotiationToken.NegTokenResp.MechListMic, hex data = 01 00 00 00 78 1E E9 4A DB 99 7F E9 00 00 00 00**

SecBuffer SignBuffers[2];

SignBufferDesc.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION; // SECBUFFER_VERSION = 0

SignBufferDesc.cBuffers = 2;

SignBufferDesc.pBuffers = SignBuffers;

SignBuffers[0] = 30 0C 06 0A 2B 06 01 04 01 82 37 02 02 0A;

SignBuffers[1] = 01 00 00 00 78 1E E9 4A DB 99 7F E9 00 00 00 00;

SignBuffers[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_DATA; // SECBUFFER_DATA = 1

SignBuffers[1].BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN; // SECBUFFER_TOKEN = 2

Can anyone please tell me what information do I need to use inside **HMAC-MD5 (key, data)** algorithm to generate **mechListMIC for SessionSetup Response** and how?

If it is possible to create a step-by-step example using my test case to calculate **mechListMIC** for **‘SessionSetup Response, Unknown message type’** response, that would be very helpful for me. Please let me know if you need any further information.

**Thanks,

Shishir**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the answer in MSDN site
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/gu-IN/os_fileservices/thread/d00b4e1a-077b-4620-99c7-da7bf86d5212